# How to find the primary key of deleted records with JDBC.?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I want to know how to find the primary key of the deleted records through the JDBC connection.

If my query like following then what will be the primary key of deleted records?

```
 String sqlDelete = "DELETE FROM devicesequences WHERE deviceId = 20;
```

What is the primary key of the deleted record?

Comment: I think there's no standard way to do that. If you need this kind of information, you must enable / implement some audit mechanism in the DB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a second query. And of course you need to execute it before running the `DELETE` query.

```
SELECT id FROM devicesequences WHERE deviceId = 20;
```

assuming that `id` is the name of your primary key column.

Comment: what about transactions and isolation levels?

Comment: @f1sh i got the idea from your answer. Thanks for your idea...:)

Comment: most likely a List or Set should be returned

Comment: @Leo You are absolutely correct, the two queries have to be part of the same transaction. But the "basicness" of this question suggests not to go too deep with this topic...

Comment: @stultuske yeah it return the result set with multiple row.

Comment: @Jatin_g what @Leo means is that your database table might be modified between the ``SELECT`` and the ``DELETE`` statements. In that case you can run into certain problems that you are probably not yet aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can delete any arbitrary row (or set of rows) at any time: no, there's no way to tell WHICH row (or rows) you most recently deleted.

You can, however, create a "trigger" to save this information for you.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html

Comment: @mitksoft i am going to try your idea, Thanks for you suggestion..:)